# Url changed but content not

Tags: asp.net, url, url-routing

I have corrected my web site's url by url routing in asp.net webform.
now pages url is :
for example producs;
site . com/product/101/pc
the content that show is pc's content.
if I changed it to 
site . com/product/101/Hi
the content that show is pc's page.
because 101 is pc's id in database.
now I want  if pc changed in url but 101 still,automaticlly redirect to the page that id refer to.please help me

Answer (score 0):

well i don't understand what is your actual problem 
but i have use URL routing with sending ID in it its working fine for me 
let me show you my code

```
 public static void UrlRouting(RouteCollection RC, string RoutName, string routeUrl, string Page)
    {
        RC.MapPageRoute(RoutName, routeUrl, Page);
    }
```

Use this function for routing in global.ascx like

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
   UrlRouting(RouteTable.Routes, "Showproduct", "product/{productID}", "~/products.aspx");
        }
```

& then get the value of productID on product.aspx

```
   if (RouteData.Values["productID"] != null){
          string  productID= RouteData.Values["productID"].ToString();
//Use your query here and assign this product ID to Your column 
}
```

One more thing if you are using html anchor tag then you should use resolveUrl function like

```
<a href='<%# ResolveUrl("~/product/"+Eval("YourProductIDColumn")) %>'>ProductNam</a>
```

& if you are redirecting on the page from code behind then use this like that

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("Showproduct", new { productID = yourProductIDValue });
```

Hope this will help :)